# Branch invariant directory in git repository

Tags: git, version-control, branch

Is there a way to make a directory in a git repository *always the same in all branches*?

The scenario which I have in mind is the following: consider you are working on a project/thesis where you are experimenting a lot (i.e. creating a branch, try something out/do measurements/statistics, typically not merge it back to master) plus you write a documentation/thesis where you want to have content/results from all (incl. experimental) branches. Switching back and forth the branch of course works for the experiments itself, but for your doc/thesis you really only want a single *current version* at all times.

An alternative would be to put your doc into a separate branch (like some projects do), but I personally find it annoying to always switch whenever you want to add something to your doc/thesis.

Also I could have two repositories, but that somehow goes against my intuition of a repository as *the thing that contains all stuff about project XY*...

Comment: you could use a separate branch for your thesis and check it out in its own working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into the simple but clunky [git submodule](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) or the slicker but more complicated [git subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt).

They let you embed a separate repository into your repository, which might serve your purpose.